# Natural Logarithm algebra in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, math, natural-logarithm

I have the following equation:

```
import numpy as np

d = (x - y) / np.log((x - z) / (y - z))
```

Where I am trying to find `x`

Is this possible in `numpy` or other python libraries? In this case, could you please provide sample code of how to do it with this specific problem?

Comment: So what you want is to have x(d,y,z) ?

Comment: I need to rewrite the equation with x = etc...

Comment: You can use `sympy` to find $x(d,y,z)$ and then calculate it using `numpy`.

Comment: When i try to paste x(d,y,z)$ in the terminal (even after setting dummy variables x = 50, y = 40, z = 30) I get "invalid syntax" error after running the code. sympy was imported as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably use just `sympy` and their solver:
[sympy Library Solver](https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/solvers/solvers.html)

```
from sympy import solve, log, exp
from sympy.abc import x,y,z,d

f = (x - y) / log((x - z) / (y - z)) - d

solution = solve(f, x)
```

And the output is giving me is

```
[-d*LambertW(-(y - z)*exp(-(y - z)/d)/d) + z]
```

Comment: fantastic! works. thanks for introducing me to this library!